# Subplot with custom colorbar range from group of plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, colorbar

I want to plot a group of contour maps with a colorbar for this group. As the colorbar is dependent on the subplot you specify in the `ax` argument, the range of the colorbar does not reflect the range of the values for all the plots in the first 2 columns.[image]

Can I specify the first colorbar (on the left) that reflects the minimum (`mina=-500`) and maximum (`maxa=500`) values on the ticks?

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
v = np.arange(-180,181,15)
y,x = np.meshgrid(v,v)

p1 = 500*np.sin(x+y)
p2 = x
p3 = -500*np.sin(3*x+y)
p4 = y
p5 = -200*np.cos(x+5*y)
p6 = 100*np.cos(x+6*y)

f, ax = plt.subplots(2,3,sharex='row',sharey='col',figsize=(4,6))

mina = min(min(p1.reshape(625,)),min(p2.reshape(625,)),min(p3.reshape(625,)),min(p4.reshape(625,)))
maxa = max(max(p1.reshape(625,)),max(p2.reshape(625,)),max(p3.reshape(625,)),max(p4.reshape(625,)))
minb = min(min(p5.reshape(625,)),min(p6.reshape(625,)))
maxb = max(max(p5.reshape(625,)),max(p6.reshape(625,)))

ax[0,0].contourf(x,y,p1,20,vmin=mina,vmax=maxa)
ax[0,0].set(adjustable='box-forced', aspect='equal')
l0 = ax[1,0].contourf(x,y,p2,20,vmin=mina,vmax=maxa)
ax[1,0].set(adjustable='box-forced', aspect='equal')
ax[0,1].contourf(x,y,p3,20,vmin=mina,vmax=maxa)
ax[0,1].set(adjustable='box-forced', aspect='equal')
ax[1,1].contourf(x,y,p4,20,vmin=mina,vmax=maxa)
ax[1,1].set(adjustable='box-forced', aspect='equal')
ax[0,2].contourf(x,y,p5,20,vmin=minb,vmax=maxb)
ax[0,2].set(adjustable='box-forced', aspect='equal')
l1 = ax[1,2].contourf(x,y,p6,20,vmin=minb,vmax=maxb)
ax[1,2].set(adjustable='box-forced', aspect='equal')

f.colorbar(l0, ax=list(ax[1,0:2]),orientation='horizontal', pad=0.2)
f.colorbar(l1, ax=ax[1,2],orientation='horizontal', aspect=10, pad=0.2)

plt.setp([a.get_xticklabels() for a in ax[0,:]], visible=False)
plt.setp([a.get_yticklabels() for a in ax[:,1]], visible=False)
plt.setp([a.get_yticklabels() for a in ax[:,2]], visible=False)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be accomplished by setting `mina = minb = -500` and `maxa = maxb = 500`?

Comment: The specifications say that the first 2 columns have one color bar, and the last column has another. Also, `mina != minb` and `maxa != maxb`.  Nevertheless, this does not solve the problem, as the colorbar range ticks follow the specified contour plot.

Comment: What exactly *are* the specifications? If you are specific about what exactly the limits of each of the subplots should be and what limits each of the two colorbars, we can find a solution.

Comment: I edited the post. Basically, the left colorbar needs to reflect the full range of the four plots (on the first 2 columns), i.e., reflects the min and max value on the ticks based on the min and max value for all the four plots. This is why I computed `mina` and `maxa` for the left colorbar.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case the solution is easy: Use the first plot as ScalarMappable for the colorbar

```
l0 = ax[0,0].contourf(x,y,p1,20,vmin=mina,vmax=maxa)
#...
l1 = ax[0,2].contourf(x,y,p5,20,vmin=minb,vmax=maxb)
#...
```

[image]

In the more general case, where potentially one plot contains the minimum value and *another* plot contains the maximum value, the solution would be to create a ScalarMappable specifically for the colorbar.

```
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap="viridis", norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=mina, vmax=maxa))
sm.set_array([])
f.colorbar(sm, ax=list(ax[1,0:2]),orientation='horizontal', pad=0.2)
```